# Fixing 'if'-'else' construct in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms

How do I do this? I have an `if`-`else` statement like this (not exact code but a symbolic idea):

```
if(formNull)
{
   MessageBox.Show("empty")
}
else if(FormNotNull)
{
   // I have validation if/elses here for input fields like
   if(regex textbx1)
   {
      error
   }
   else
   {
      normal
   }
   if(regex textbx2)
   {
      error
   }
   else
   {
      normal
   }
   //Some more like this

}  <<<<<<<<<<<< It stops here and never goes in the next 'else' statement even if the form is OK.
else
{
   DBConn.myMethod(a, b, c, etc.)
   if true
   {
      success!;
   }
   else
   {
      failed!;
   }
}
```

I tried some nesting combinations, but nothing worked.

Comment: It should go into that next to last `else` if `formNull` and `FormNotNull` are both `false`, which doesn't seem likely based on the names..

Comment: Form is either null or it isn't. There is no third possibility.

Comment: How are you setting the value(s) being checked in your `IF` / `ELSE-IF`? As others said, if they're "opposite" booleans (ie if `FormNull` is `true` then `FormNotNull` must be `false`) then there is no chance you'll ever escape those two conditions you're checking for. We'll need to see the actual code to tell you what the problem is more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for suggestions. I simply used the separate textChanged events with Regex for errors and used simple if-statement like this

```
if (FormNull)
{
    Message.Show("error");
}
else
{
    DBConn.myMthod(a,b,c)
        if(true)
        {
           sucess;
        }
        else
        {
            failed;
        }
}
```

Just wanted to know the other option for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like there's nothing left, as you already handled all cases in the `if` and `else if`.

```
if(formNull)
{
    // goes here when `formNull` is true
}
else if(FormNotNull)
{
    // goes here when `FormNotNull` is true and `formNull` is false
}
else        
{
    // goes here in any other case (but I guess there is no other case left)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That just means your two conditions (in the `if` and `else if` statements) are returning `true`. If either ever returns `true`, you will never go into your `else` block (both MUST be `false`).